# I'm looking for a low-parts-count Arduino <-> phone & POTS line interface

Tags: arduino, telephone

[UPDATE - I found a partial solution here - http://www.joes.com/intercom/index.html - it's an intercom, not a full PBX.]

I'm looking for links to circuit design  for an Arduino-controlled mini-PBX that can use traditional analog phones.  I'm looking for something with features like the [often-cited Elektor circuit](http://techdoc.kvindesland.no/radio/ymse3/20081009163935804.pdf) from the early 1990s.

I see lots of schematics and circuit ideas, but Ideally I can find a "telephone shield" that I can plug phones and modems into, then eventually plug that into a phone line for connecting elsewhere, a phone line interface will be easier than trying to get any kind of VOIP stack running on the Arduino, obviously.

FCC registration number shouldn't be required here, as I'm expecting to  plug into a VOIP appliance port, not an real analog phone line.  I do have about 30 surplus Apple-Cat DAAs if I need to use those.

Background/Inspirations:

- [Sparkfun's ring voltage generator](http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/50)
- [Telephone Interface Project](http://brohogan.blogspot.com/search/label/Telephone%20Interface)

Comment: If I understood it correctly you want a shield for Arduino where you can just plug the phone and have everything working. But then there is little value in using Arduino: why don't you follow that tutorial?

Comment: I think you're going to have to build your own. I'd suggest either building a stackable shield (use I2C to allow multiple to be stacked), or a separate board that communicates over serial (or is entirely standalone as clabacchio suggests - embed your own MCU).

Comment: I looked at this very thing- The problem is that is illegal in most countries to hook up un certified devices to the phone line.. hence no commercial availabilities.. The circuit is pretty easy but the problem is different voltages. A hint- takin apart old modems you find everything you need in there to make your own. PBX thingi ma doo daa.. If u explain a bit maybe there is another solution.. Look at asterisk.org or store.digium.com for some new age stuff

Comment: This sounds like an idea for a shield and you want us to find a supplier, this is inherently locked in time, as right now there is no option, but you could try to build one? Or someone else could, then it could stop being supplied, this is never ending.

Comment: @Kortuk - I am interesting in building a POTS <-> SIP (any VoIP) gateway and want to ask a question about what parts to use for the POTS part. If there is single chip or low part count solution that is not out of production. Should I post a new question? I do not want to post something similar only to be closed again!

Comment: @LordLoh. I would narrow it down and ask about the specific section and as a new question.